# J's # operator: why not reversed?

Tags: language-design, j, apl

I've been studying J for the last few weeks, and something that has really buggered me is the dyadic case of the `#` operator: the only way I've used it yet is similar to the following:

```
(1 p: a) # a
```

If this were reversed, the parenthesis could be omitted:

```
a #~ 1 p: a
```

Why was there chosen not to take the reverse of the current arguments? Backwards familiarity with APL, or something I'm completely overlooking?

Comment: Becaue that's the way they designed it. Unless you can get a designer to answer here, all you will get is more or less uninformed opinion. Off topic.

Comment: Firstly, most primitives (like `#`,`{`,`$`, etc) have a mask/filter as a left argument and the object as the right argument. Secondly, when there is a point in writing `# a` , you'd also want the expression `x # a` to mean something to you (and vice versa).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, J's primitives are designed to take "primary data" on the right, and "control data" on the left.

The distinction between "primary" and "control" data is not sharp, but in general one would expect "primary" data to vary more often than "control" data. That is, one would expect that the "control" data is less likely to be calculated than the "primary" data.

The reason for that design choice is exactly as you point out: because if the data that is more likely to be calculated (as opposed to fixed in advanced) appears on the right, then more J phrases could be expressed as simple trains or pipelines of verbs, without excessive parenthesization (given that J executed left-to-right).

Now, in the case of `#`, which data is more likely to be calculated?  You're 100% right that the filter (or mask) is very likely to be calculated. However, *the data to be filtered is **almost certain*** to be calculated.  Where did you get your `a`, for example?

QED.

PS: if your `a` can be calculated by some J verb, as in `a=: ...`, then your whole result, filter and all, can be expressed with `primeAs =: 1&p: # ...` .

PPS: Note the `1&p:`, there. That's another example of "control" vs "primary": the `1` is control data - you can tell because it's forever bound to `p:` - and it's fixed. And so, uncoincidentally, `p:` was designed to take it as a *left* argument.

PPPS:  This concept of "control data appears on the left" has been expressed many different ways. You can find one round-up of veteran Jers' explanations here:  http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/general/2007-May/030079.html .

Comment: And there is one notable exception to that: dyadic /: It takes array to sort ("primary data") on the left and sort key ("control data") on the right. Gets me every time.

Comment: There are a few exceptions: compare `e.` with `i.`, for example, or `|` with `%`. Sometimes the exceptions are in made in pursuit of consistency (e.g. whether monad or dyad, `y` tells `/:` *how to sort*, and tells both `fread` and `fwrite` *the name of the file*). Other times, exceptions are made for backwards compatibility with mathematics (it would be *really confusing* if `%` were "consistent" and took control data on the left: eight thirds would be written `3 % 8`!).